Safe replay issue, sdk/cli help needed
I would kindly like to ask someone to help someone being not a dev (me) to verify why during safe recreation (I mistakenly sent my funds from the Bybit 62 SAFE erc to optimism address).
Why there is an error during safe recreation on ethereum mainnet?

Video guide to recreate safe on different chain;

Tenderly to simulate transaction;

Did setup of CLI on my Windows, tried initial commands with Docker;

I already have the safe-cli client running.


I cannot set my address as default in safe-cli.
Would you be so kind and tell me what I do wrong?
Instead of the private key of owner option, I placed my wallet address.
docker run -it safeglobal/safe-cli safe-cli --owners 0xc31D74165d4490E6dEedC070CaE7aa24d2279799 --safe-contract 0xfb1bffc9d739b8d520daf37df666da4c687191ea
--fallback-handler 0x017062a1de2fe6b99be3d9d37841fed19f573804 --proxy-factory 0xc31d74165d4490e6deedc070cae7aa24d2279799
--threshold 1 --salt-nonce 1650616206787 https: // mainnet. infura. io/v3/ 0xa37E918C33Cfa02d59FB34Ddb1348a2075e208eE

safe-cli 0xc31D74165d4490E6dEedC070CaE7aa24d2279799 https: //mainnet. infura.io/v3/

safe-creator https:// 
 mainnet.infura.io/v3/ 0xa37E918C33Cfa02d59FB34Ddb1348a2075e208eE


docker run -it safeglobal/safe-cli safe-cli 0xc31D74165d4490E6dEedC070CaE7aa24d2279799 https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/

docker run -it safeglobal/safe-cli safe-cli  0xc31D74165d4490E6dEedC070CaE7aa24d2279799 https:  //ethereum-rpc. 
 publicnode.com

https: //i. 8sstatic. net/frChAz6t.jpg
Simulation wallet replay on eth mainnet worked perfect. The real transaction keeps failing. One suggestion was that my rpc status in not healthy

[

I searched forums here and I believe no such case exists
(Safe-Cli additional commands, proxy failure in spite of good syntax, metamask rpc issues)
, but correct me if I am wrong
Could you kindly guide please?



Update to CLI establishing On pc (17.06.24)
imgur.com/a/u1onqrS here is the result of replacing api with my wallet private key. I erased all key and private data, for safety as you guided. Some error remains. Could you kindly look into it and guide please? Thank you
imgur.com/a/u1onqrS here is the result of replacing api with my wallet private key. I erased all key and private data, for safety as you guided. Some error remains. Could you kindly look into it and guide please? Thank you











It looks that there are some extra spaces in the URL of the nodes you sent on your example. This is likely to make the CLI fail. Can you also try after creating an account on infura and adding your public key like so: https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR-API-KEY
To manually deploy this Safe, please:

Go to https://etherscan.io/address/0xc22834581ebc8527d974f8a1c97e1bea4ef910bc#writeContract.

Click "Connect to Web3" button and connect your wallet (Metamask or other). Your wallet should be set to the network "Ethereum Mainnet" and have sufficient funds for the transaction.

Click "createProxyWithNonce (0x1688f0b9)"

In the field "_singleton (address)", paste this value: 0xfb1bffc9d739b8d520daf37df666da4c687191ea

In the field "initializer (bytes)" paste this value (double click and copy to make sure to select all 714 characters):


0xb63e800d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140000000000000000000000000017062a1de2fe6b99be3d9d37841fed19f5738040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000a37e918c33cfa02d59fb34ddb1348a2075e208ee0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000


In the field "saltNonce (uint256)", paste this value: 1650616206787
Click "write" and confirm the transaction in your wallet. It should take ~15 seconds to confirm.

Since the simulation went through on Tenderly, simply sending this transaction should get you unstuck.
Hope it works; Best, Louis

Yes, you are right sir. I did it as there is URL limit.

https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/1c3cbb616d224156bbefcf117a68d416 this is my api. In powershell it tells my private key is wrong

Added 3 screens (bottom) with more attempt (infura api , added rpc into safe app on pc)

For your own safety please do not share private API keys or wallet private keys to this thread. Please also avoid adding screenshot pictures as they make debugging/copy and paste difficult. In the screenshot you provided, it seems that you are trying to use your Infura API key as your wallet key. Please regenerate a new API key as this one has been leaked, and use your own wallet private key as the parameter for the CLI. Hope it helps; Best, Louis

Thank you, will do

Tried couple of times, still not recreate but there is progression the only error I get is

Tried many more times and safe was not recreated yet. There is progression though. The only syntax error I get (finally last one) Is : this is not checksummed owners address or similar. Could you kindly guide please which one is the owner address, how to check it and how to make checksumed address please? Thank you very much for your help

Sure! You can checksum your addresses here: https://ethsum.netlify.app/

Thank you ! Tried with everything that you provided me. Thank you for your time and expertise naturally! Still cannot recreate safe on ethereum mainnet. I am doing this with docker plus cmd (Windows + R) instead of wsl.exe (no linux subsystem). Also docker cannot see container nor data. Also i receive messenger that my contract on ethereum mainnet does not exist. Could you tell me in your free time could this be no linux subsystem case ? I have to install it properly and try again ? I attached new screenshots with error in main post for greater insight for you. Could you kindly guide please?

Apologies that I am not a software developer but wont give up easily. Troubleshooting itself is great experience. Thank you

No worries! I'm here to help :) Can you try again with linux subsystem for windows installed? Thanks in advance

Thank you ! You are the best. Managed to install wsl properly. New screenshot, also had error with docker connection.Was able to find it and solve issue with google. What is left is to recreate with proper syntax. Correct ? But each time I try, I get different than wanted address. With safe support found salt nonce, proxy, fallback, handler but still output is different. Using infura with api rpc, and one out of two addresses 0xc31d74165d4490e6deedc070cae7aa24d2279799 wallet to be recreated on eth mainnet and 0xf9D445a46D65427550174ec2A49FceFA3dae7f8D Could you guide pls ?

The parameters entered should be exactly the same as for the Safe you are trying to recreate. I edited my answer to try a new approach, simply using Metamask. Could you please let me know if this worked? Thanks

Actually we tried that 48 days ago with safe support. After that they sent me here

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xac8007c262ba9442ba5f2b2b1fd86e6f7c0988b73b0bb72728495c989e80b736  https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9aa87ed9602720e72e79d2b10a3d7499a442c3d9bb7bbfed6ec774631f6db147   Here are examples, sir. If possible, after 6 attempts I would like not to send more transactions unless we are certain it will work since cost will exceed SAFE value trapped. Thank you for understanding

It looks like the transaction receipts you sent are 51 days old and do not contain the correct transaction data. To help you prepare and execute the transaction, I edited my answer again to provide detailed steps to follow. Please follow them carefully! Sending this transaction will work and should get your funds unstuck. Can you let me know if it worked without issues? Thanks in advance. Best, Louis

Managed to create this https://etherscan.io/tx/0x69c5b9b6be64cc3fbab51f438c4f1d433b6209c701a2f6c173a5228e449fe5ab used your guide sir, still cannot see my 62.42651 SAFE on eth contract address https://optimistic.etherscan.io/address/0xc22834581ebc8527d974f8a1c97e1bea4ef910bc#multichain-portfolio that thing was created, absolutely another address I believe.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xc31D74165d4490E6dEedC070CaE7aa24d2279799 On the other hand if I click here https://etherscan.io/token/0x5afe3855358e112b5647b952709e6165e1c1eeee?a=0xc31D74165d4490E6dEedC070CaE7aa24d2279799 go to write contract I see Transfer all tokens with address token owned by this contract to beneficiary.
token (address)
token (address)
beneficiary (address) If it does what it is written, perhaps maybe we can use that function ?

Will have to tell that I used your guide on mobile phone with another address which is 2/2 signer in my safe wallet. Does it matter if contract is created with 1st or 2nd signer ? Via PC that contract call is not working properly. Attached new screenshot telling that transaction will most likely fail and huge price. That is why I did it with 2nd wallet with privileges on mobile. Could you kindly guide sir ?

Will also try something else with CLI and let you know sir

Is there another method we could try sir to recover SAFE / Recreate wallet on eth mainnet and might work properly? Could you kindly guide please?

Is there any other solution? Could someone guide please?
